# Weird behaviour of the fetch when running npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, fiddler

My setup is very simple and small:

```
C:\temp\npm [master]> tree /f
Folder PATH listing for volume OSDisk
Volume serial number is F6C4-7BEF
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   1.js
│   package.json
│
└───.vscode
        launch.json

C:\temp\npm [master]> cat .\package.json
{
  "name": "node-modules",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "emitter": "http://github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz",
    "global": "https://github.com/component/global/archive/v2.0.1.tar.gz"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
C:\temp\npm [master]> npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.14.12 node/v14.16.1 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\p11f70f\.npmrc
https-proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/"
proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/"
strict-ssl = false

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\p11f70f\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\temp\npm
; HOME = C:\Users\p11f70f
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

C:\temp\npm [master]>
```

Notes:

- The proxy addresses correspond to Fiddler.
- Notice that the `emitter` dependency url uses http whereas the `global` uses https.

When I run `npm install` it starts and then hangs very quickly. And I know why, because Fiddler tells me:
[image]

The request is:

```
GET http://github.com:80/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
connection: keep-alive
user-agent: npm/6.14.12 node/v14.16.1 win32 x64
npm-in-ci: false
npm-scope: 
npm-session: 74727385b32ebcbf
referer: install
pacote-req-type: tarball
pacote-pkg-id: registry:undefined@http://github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: github.com:80
```

And the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://github.com:80/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz
```

Now this is BS, pardon my French, because the returned Location value of **https://github.com:80/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz** is invalid. But I suppose the server is not very smart - it just redirects to https without changing anything else, including the port, which remains 80 - good for http, wrong for https. This explains the hanging - the fetch API used by npm seems to retry at progressively longer delays which creates an illusion of hanging.

Debugging npm brings me to the following code inside **C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\index.js**:

```
  return opts.Promise.resolve(body).then(body => fetch(uri, {
    agent: opts.agent,
    algorithms: opts.algorithms,
    body,
    cache: getCacheMode(opts),
    cacheManager: opts.cache,
    ca: opts.ca,
    cert: opts.cert,
    headers,
    integrity: opts.integrity,
    key: opts.key,
    localAddress: opts['local-address'],
    maxSockets: opts.maxsockets,
    memoize: opts.memoize,
    method: opts.method || 'GET',
    noProxy: opts['no-proxy'] || opts.noproxy,
    Promise: opts.Promise,
    proxy: opts['https-proxy'] || opts.proxy,
    referer: opts.refer,
    retry: opts.retry != null ? opts.retry : {
      retries: opts['fetch-retries'],
      factor: opts['fetch-retry-factor'],
      minTimeout: opts['fetch-retry-mintimeout'],
      maxTimeout: opts['fetch-retry-maxtimeout']
    },
    strictSSL: !!opts['strict-ssl'],
    timeout: opts.timeout
  }).then(res => checkResponse(
    opts.method || 'GET', res, registry, startTime, opts
  )))
```

And when I stop at the right moment, this boils down to the following values:

```
uri
'http://github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz'
```

```
agent:undefined
algorithms:['sha1']
body:undefined
ca:null
cache:'default'
cacheManager:'C:\\Users\\p11f70f\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_cacache'
cert:null
headers:{
    npm-in-ci:false
    npm-scope:''
    npm-session:'413f9b25525c452a'
    pacote-pkg-id:'registry:undefined@http://github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz'
    pacote-req-type:'tarball'
    referer:'install'
    user-agent:'npm/6.14.12 node/v14.16.1 win32 x64'
}
integrity:undefined
key:null
localAddress:undefined
maxSockets:50
method:'GET'
noProxy:null
proxy:'http://127.0.0.1:8888/'
referer:'install'
retry:{retries: 2, factor: 10, minTimeout: 10000, maxTimeout: 60000}
strictSSL:false
timeout:0
```

I have omitted two values and I truly do not know their significance - `opt.Promise` and `memoize`. It is possible that they are crucial, I do not know.

Anyway, when I step over this statement, the aforementioned session appears in Fiddler with the bogus url of http://github.com:80/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz and I do not understand - how come? The debugger clearly shows that the `uri` parameter passed to fetch does not specify the port number.

I thought maybe it is some kind of a non string type, but `typeof uri` returns `'string'`.

I have even written a tiny reproduction to execute just this request using the same arguments, except for the `opt.Promise` and `memoize`:

```
const fetch = require('make-fetch-happen')

fetch('http://github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz', {
    algorithms: ['sha1'],
    cache: 'default',
    cacheManager: 'C:\\Users\\p11f70f\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_cacache',
    headers:{
        "npm-in-ci":false,
        "npm-scope":"",
        "npm-session":"00b5bb97075e3c35",
        "user-agent":"npm/6.14.12 node/v14.16.1 win32 x64",
        "referer":"install",
        "pacote-req-type":"tarball",
        "pacote-pkg-id":"registry:undefined@http://github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz"
    },
    maxSockets: 50,
    method: 'GET',
    proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888',
    referer: 'install',
    retry: {
      retries: 2,
      factor: 10,
      minTimeout: 10000,
      maxTimeout: 60000
    },
    strictSSL: false,
    timeout: 0
  }).then(res => console.log(res))
```

But it shows up correctly in Fiddler - no port is added and hence the redirection works fine.

When there is no Fiddler (and hence no proxy) everything works correctly too, but I am very much curious to know why it does not work with Fiddler.

What is going on here?

Comment: Could it be something to do with your `https-proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/"`? What proxy is it? How does it handle redirects?

Comment: It is Fiddler. Let me update the question.

Comment: Ah right, sorry. I forgot how Fiddler works. Have you tried using a non-proxy based monitor like Wireshark (just to remove that as a problem)?

Comment: Since without Fiddler it works, this is surely Fiddler, but I want to understand why.

Comment: I edited the question a little bit. Replaced the `verbose` dependency with 2 raw github dependencies.

Comment: The redirect from `http://github.com:80` -> `https://github.com:80` is a bug of github, you should open an issue there.